# Change a number to a word using jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, numbers

I have a number (a stock number) that is generated with a CMS that display how many items are left in stock. I would like to change the number to either say 'In stock' or 'Out of stock' depending if its equal to or greater than zero.

I have this snippet but for some reason it changes the number to 'In stock' no matter what it is - so even when its '0' it says 'In stock'.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong because in this snippet its even changing the module example thats not even a number...

```js
var number = $(".productStock").text();

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (number == "0") {
    $(".productStock").text('Out of stock')
  } else {
    $(".productStock").text('In stock')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="productStock">{tag_instock}</li> <!--this is the module-->
  <li class="productStock">0</li> <!--I want this to say 'Out of stock'-->
  <li class="productStock">45</li> <!--I want this to say 'In stock'-->
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you really have 3 `<li>` elements having the same classname ? `productStock`

Comment: @RohitAgre ...? Shared classes is absolutely fine - it's *exactly* what they are intended for.

Comment: I get it that classnames may be shared and even appear more than once. I just wanted the OP to confirm whether they appear together. or the values `0`, `45` are replaced for the `{tag_instock}` @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - they are just examples of whats on the page. The first one is how the code looks and the other two are samples of whats generated. There is only ever one on the page.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you have is that you only look at the first `.productStock` element (outside of the document.ready handler too, but that's another issue). You need to loop through them all and check their values individually.

To do this you can provide a function to the `text()` method which returns the new value to set based on its current one, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".productStock").text(function(i, t) {
    return t == "0" ? 'Out of stock' : 'In stock';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="productStock">{tag_instock}</li>
  <li class="productStock">0</li>
  <li class="productStock">45</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - Thank you! I clearly still have a lot to learn about constructing jQuery...

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Here we need to traverse `li`. So if we want to use the same class `.productStock` its good to use `each(function(){})`
Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g53n1qon/#&togetherjs=iT5TSn6fui):

JS:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $(".productStock").each(function(){
      if($(this).text() == "0"){
            $(this).text('Out of stock')
        } else {
            $(this).text('In stock')
        }
      });      
   });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Definitely I will :)